# Unable to delete child nodes of a parent node (Devexpress TreeList)

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, xtratreelist

I am trying to delete focused node along with it's all child nodes (if any) from `TreeList`. The problem is I am unable to retrieve the child nodes. I tried 2 approaches:

1. I used `TreeListNodeIterator` which returns a `TreeListNodes` object containing childs of the focused row:

   ```
   Public Class TreeListOperationGetChildNodes
           Inherits TreeListOperation
           Private _child_nodes As TreeListNodes

       Public Sub New(tree As TreeList)
           _child_nodes = New TreeListNodes(tree)
       End Sub

       Public Overrides Sub Execute(node As DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode)
           _child_nodes.Add(node)
       End Sub

       Public ReadOnly Property ChildNodes() As TreeListNodes
           Get
               Return _child_nodes
           End Get
       End Property

   End Class
   ```

This `child_nodes` object is then used to delete all nodes from `TreeList`:

```
Dim child_nodes As TreeListNodes = New TreeListNodes(DataTreeList)
Dim op As New TreeListOperationGetChildNodes(DataTreeList)
Dim nodes As TreeListNodes = New TreeListNodes(DataTreeList)
DataTreeList.NodesIterator.DoLocalOperation(op, nodes)
child_nodes = op.ChildNodes 

For Each node As TreeListNode In child_nodes
   DataTreeList.DeleteNode(node)
Next
```

2. Another Approach I tried was to Loop through all the nodes of the treelist and see if their `parent_id` is equals to focused node `id`. If yes then put them into a stack. At the end, for each node in stack call delete node.

   ```
   Dim nodeStack As New Stack(Of DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode)
   nodeStack.Push(DataTreeList.FocusedNode)
   FillStack(DataTreeList.FocusedNode, nodeStack)
   For i As Integer = 0 To nodeStack.Count - 1 Step +1
       DataTreeList.DeleteNode(nodeStack.Pop)
   Next

   Private Sub FillStack(ByVal node As DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode, ByVal nodestack As Stack(Of DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode))
       For Each childnode As DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode In DataTreeList.Nodes

           If DirectCast(DataTreeList.GetDataRecordByNode(childnode), Data).ParentID = _
              DirectCast(DataTreeList.GetDataRecordByNode(node), Data).ID Then

               nodestack.Push(childnode)
               FillStack(childnode, nodestack)

           End If
       Next
   End Sub
   ```

The issue with above code snippets:

1. Here the node iterator is returning `chlid_nodes` empty (no child nodes found)
2. In `FillDeleteStack` `DataTreeList.Nodes` contains only 2 nodes that is only parent nodes. So stack is always empty.

I can not understand why I am not able to iterate through child nodes. Why the collection of nodes in `TreeList` contains only parent nodes and not child nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0. To delete focused node along with it's all child nodes you can simply use [`TreeList.DeleteNode`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_DeleteNodetopic) method:

```vb
DataTreeList.DeleteNode(DataTreeList.FocusedNode)
```

1. You are using `TreeListNodes(TreeList)` constructor which creates an **empty** nodes collection. If you want to get the collection of existing nodes than you can use [`TreeList.Nodes`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_Nodestopic) or [`TreeListNode.Nodes`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraTreeListNodesTreeListNode_Nodestopic) properties:

```vb
nodes = DataTreeList.Nodes
' or
nodes = DataTreeList.FocusedNode.Nodes
```

2. `TreeList.Nodes` property returns the collection of the `TreeList`'s **root** nodes. If you want to get all visible nodes in `TreeList` then you can use [`TreeList.GetNodeList`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_GetNodeListtopic) method.

Comment: 1. I am creating TreeListNodes(TreeList) constructor which creates an empty nodes collection -Right. But then I am using TreeListNodeIterator and adding child nodes to this collection. Meaning at the end it should have all the child nodes.  2. That's something confusing for me. I have always used TreeList.Nodes and was able to retrieve all nodes (including child nodes). But I always see unpredicted behaviour while working with TreeList. Anyway I am gonna try with GetNodeList. Thanks nempoBu4!

Comment: @LittleMissSunshine You are using your iterator with empty collection: `DataTreeList.NodesIterator.DoLocalOperation(op, nodes)`, where the `nodes` variable is empty collection: `Dim nodes As TreeListNodes = New TreeListNodes(DataTreeList)`.

Comment: @LittleMissSunshine Have you tried `DataTreeList.DeleteNode(DataTreeList.FocusedNode)`?

Comment: Oh yes! I somehow missed node = DataTreeList.FocusedNode assignment!! :( . Yes I tried DeleteNode also, but it was giving Operation not supported exception , which I today realized was because my datasource of TreeList(list) does not Support delete. But now it's ressolved. After doing correction with my node iterator,it's working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should use this line of code if you want to delete the node and all of its children when you click on a delete

```
<SettingsEditing AllowRecursiveDelete="True"></SettingsEditing>
```

its the Recursive Delete that do the task